# WinDivert ignore tor traffic

Tags: c, windows, networking

I'm looked at basil00's TorWall(https://github.com/basil00/TorWall) and cannot understand, how it is possible to ignore traffic that goes from tor?

I'm writing my own torwall and my goal is to add support of different types of proxies(socks5, http[s]). I stuck with problem that inbound traffic from tor.exe is going through the filter. I definitely missed something because torwall is working well.

Answer (score 0):

Tallow ignores Tor traffic based on the port number, e.g. `9001`.  See the `traffic.divert` file from the Tallow repository (https://github.com/basil00/TorWall). This is a crude solution, and ideally it should be possible to instruct WinDivert to ignore traffic based on application, however such a feature does not currently exist as of 2018.